# TWinControl - What is the last stage before Destructor when the WinControl has a Valid handle?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Just before my `TCustomWinControl` is destroyed permanently, I need to do somthing with its handle.

If I try to access its handle in the `destructor` I get an error:

> "Control "xxx" has no parent window".

So what is the last stage before TWinControl Destructor where its handle (`HandleAllocated`) is still valid?

```
type
  TPanel = class(ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure DestroyWindowHandle; override;
  public
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
  end;

procedure TPanel.DestroyWindowHandle;
begin
  Beep;
  if csDestroying in ComponentState then Beep;      
  inherited;
end;

procedure TPanel.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if HandleAllocated then Beep;
  inherited;
end;
```

There is no Beep.

Comment: There is the `DestroyWindowHandle` method which you can `override` and do whatever you want with its `Handle` before calling `inherited`. But note, that `Handle` is not persistent and so that this method may be called more than once in the component's lifetime.

Comment: @TLama, but what if it's handle is being recreated?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that "something" is? The VCL is somewhat designed under the assumption that there are no such things, that either an action should be taken when the handle is destroyed (including re-creation), or an action should be taken when the control is destroyed (at which point the handle is already gone). If that assumption is incorrect, if you have a legitimate need for it, then it would help get a better answer if you can explain what the action is. Or it might turn out that it's something that you really should not be doing during destruction after all.

Comment: If the handle is being destroyed so it can be re-created, the `ControlState` property will have the `csRecreating` flag enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

It is more complex than I originally thought. Your control lives on a form, and the control's death is provoked by the death of that form. When a form is destroyed, the child windows are also destroyed. So, the Win32 API is responsible for destroying your window. The VCL keeps track of this by responding to the `WM_NCDESTROY` message:

```
procedure TWinControl.WMNCDestroy(var Message: TWMNCDestroy);
begin
  inherited;
  FHandle := 0;
  FShowing := False;
end;
```

So, I guess you could handle `WM_NCDESTROY` yourself. Look for `csRecreating` in `ControlState` to switch behaviour based on whether or not the window destruction is related to VCL window re-creation.

An interesting point to note here is that there's no reason why the destructor of your control has to be called. If it is not owned by the form then your control won't be destroyed. You could then re-parent it onto another form. So `WM_NCDESTROY` really is the right hook.

---

**Original answer**

The source code of the destructor looks like this:

```
destructor TWinControl.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
  Instance: TControl;
begin
  Destroying;
  if FDockSite then
  begin
    FDockSite := False;
    RegisterDockSite(Self, False);
  end;
  FDockManager := nil;
  FDockClients.Free;
  if Parent <> nil then RemoveFocus(True);
  if FHandle <> 0 then DestroyWindowHandle;
  I := ControlCount;
  while I <> 0 do
  begin
    Instance := Controls[I - 1];
    Remove(Instance);
    Instance.Destroy;
    I := ControlCount;
  end;
  FBrush.Free;
{$IFDEF LINUX}
  if FObjectInstance <> nil then WinUtils.FreeObjectInstance(FObjectInstance);
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  if FObjectInstance <> nil then Classes.FreeObjectInstance(FObjectInstance);
{$ENDIF}
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

The call to the Win32 API `DestroyWindow` is made in this line:

```
if FHandle <> 0 then DestroyWindowHandle;
```

So you need to run your code before then.

You could override `DestroyWindowHandle` and do your work there. That would work well so long as the event you need to deal with is the destruction of the window. But bear in mind that `DestroyWindowHandle` will be called when the window is re-created.

If you need to do something related to the destruction of the VCL control, then you would be best overriding `BeforeDestruction`. Or as an alternative, you could override `DestroyWindowHandle` and in there test for `csDestroying` in the `ComponentState`.

Comment: But FHandle = 0 in `Destroy` for me. It is not fired at all. my desendant is `TPanel`

Comment: Well, you said you need to do something with the handle. And if it is `0` then there's nothing to do. If your requirements are different, and you need to do something during destruction, but before the handle has been destroyed, then there is `BeforeDestruction`. Or even an overridden destructor where you do your work before calling the inherited destructor.

Comment: "So what is the last stage before TWinControl Destructor where its handle (HandleAllocated) is still valid?" Did you downvoted on my question?

Comment: It is valid until the call to `DestroyWindow`. That is made from `DestroyWindowHandle`. And you can see where that is called.

Comment: OK, I found a solution: I handle the `WMDestroy` message (WM_DESTROY) with `csDestroying in ComponentState`.

Comment: However, I can see that it is more complex, using your code. Let me dig deeper.

Comment: in WMDestroy there is still a valid window handle, and it is fired before WMNCDestroy where it sets FHandle := 0. SO I think this is my only choise.

Comment: Yes, I have belatedly arrived at this conclusion too.

Comment: So, if `not csRecreating` in WM_NCDESTROY then the control is about to die permanently?